# Which ML model would be best suited for time series activity log data to predict customer retention?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I have customer activity data like the number of logins, time spent on the site, devices registered and policies changed. The data is structured on a day-day basis. i.e activity for a customer on a particular day. 
The ML model should be able to predict based on this activity whether the customer will be retained or not. 
Ideally, the model should output a bool value or the % of chances of retention.

Which ML models should I look into?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: wrong place to ask for this, please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 1):

"Which ML model would be best suited for ..."

Unfortunately, the "There is no free lunch" Theorem states that the answer will always be: "it depends". [no free lunch theorem](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-free-Lunch-Theoreme)

Fortunately though, customer Retention models are well researched [(e.g. this paper)](https://thesai.org/Downloads/Volume9No2/Paper_38-Machine_Learning_Techniques_for_Customer_Retention.pdf) and usually formulated as a simple classification Problem. Threfore you could try a few simple algorithms such:

1. Regression analysis: logistic regression.
2. Decision tree–CART.
3. Bayes algorithm: Naïve Bayesian.
4. Support Vector Machine
5. Instance – based learning: k-nearest Neighbor.
6. Ensemble learning: Ada Boost, Stochastic Gradient Boost and Random Forest.
7. Artificial neural network: Multi-layer Perceptron.
8. Linear Discriminant Analysis.

Comment: Regression won't be a good choice as in time series there is only one variable which is plotted against a time series. example: yearly sales etc

Comment: That is true, but customer Retention is a classical classification Problem. Therfore in my oppinion you would first transform the data into a non-time-series Format better suited for classification, e.g. though binning etc.

Comment: Yes in that case it would hold good. But the question is asking for time series forecast.

Answer (score 1):

**Time Series Forecasting**

Making predictions about the future is called ***extrapolation*** in the classical statistical handling of time series data.

More modern fields focus on the topic and refer to it as time series forecasting.

Forecasting involves taking models fit on historical data and using them to predict future observations.

Descriptive models can borrow for the future (i.e. to smooth or remove noise), they only seek to best describe the data.

*An important distinction in forecasting is that the future is completely unavailable and must only be estimated from what has already happened.*

If your data has some kind of trends or seasonality you may want to smooth out the data and use either of the algorithms:

**1. Moving Average Algorithm**

**2. Auto regression**

**3. ARIMA (Autoregressive Integrated Moving Average) Model**

ARIMA model is a combination of both Moving Average and Auto Regression algo.

I strongly recommend to go through this great tutorial/blog about time series forecasting using ARIMA model: https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/